# Marking .NET 5.0 EXE to avoid warings about version dependent APIs

Tags: .net-5

I'm updating projects in a .NET Framework solution containing a DLL and an EXE to target .NET 5.0. Every call from the from the EXE which touches the DLL is marked with the warning:

```
Warning CA1416  'MyDllClass.MyProperty<int>(ref int, int, string)' is supported on 'Windows' 7.0 and later
```

The [suggested actions from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/code-analysis/5.0/ca1416-platform-compatibility-analyzer#recommended-action) basically amount to either adding cruft to every call or just giving up and suppressing the warnings. Logically, I expected to be able to mark my EXE to declare that it was targeting Windows 7.0 or higher, so that it would give an exception if anyone tried to run it elsewhere, but the compiler could assume this was the baseline for all API calls. Two things I tried, neither of which helped:

Attempt 1

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>7.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

Attempt 2

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
```

What is the elegant way to address this situation? The fact that I'm in control of both projects seems like the best-case scenario.

From EXE Project:

```xml
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

From DLL Project:

```xml
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a [comment by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153355/marking-net-5-0-exe-to-avoid-warings-about-version-dependent-apis#comment115190908_65153355), I tried removing this from my EXE project:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

I also had to remove the AssemblyInfo.cs due to auto-generated fields conflicting with fields defined in there. After that, all good, no warnings. I presume the compiler is generating whatever fields it needs to keep itself happy.

I also guess that this would not be an issue on a green-field project and that I only ended up with that element somewhere in the process of migrating the application.